# Reduce the time_starttransfer time for AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services

I want to ask very simple question because I am not very experienced with AWS.

We have server on us-east-1 running ec2 machine.

When I request with POST from Turkey with domain it tooks 1 second and its

time_starttransfer takes like 900ms.

When I connect to that machine and request from inside it took ~100ms.

So basically, what should I do to reduce time_starttransfer to be able to decrease response time like AWS Global Accelerator ? My service should response less than 200ms but it actually do.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to reach a sever from halfway across the globe. Of course it’s going to take at least a second to get a response. What you want to use is AWS CloudFront.
In order to utilise CloudFront you have to deploy your API via API Gateway and enable CloudFront there. With this, requests will reach the closest AWS server to the origin of the request, reducing the distance the data needs to travel. In your case the request will go to a server in Germany as opposed to East Coast USA.

Comment: I will make a research about AWS CloudFront  but can you give me a very brief summary of what it does ?

Comment: A return trip across the atlantic takes about 100ms. So the distance is insignificant here.

Comment: Also, CloudFront won't help a post request that has to go to the origin server.

Comment: OP, ignore @F_SO_K, he doesn’t know how AWS works. I do know though

Comment: To be not confused, Ignore everything he said like I told you before

Comment: Do you have an idea what is " Execution role" building api gate way ?

Comment: Post a new question and I’ll answer there

Comment: So basically, I am creating the api gateway after that I am creating CloudFront, I need to copy api gateway's invoke URL and paste in origin domain name right?

Comment: And what will by my api type ? Regional api, edge optimized ?

Comment: Accept my answer please

Comment: Ok I have already created API Gateway, then copied invoke URL and created cloudfrount and paste to origin name. I have configured 1-2 options but other configurations are default. I can make a post request to cloudfront domain. My ms has decreased 1 second to 0.7 but not so stable.

Comment: What is not stable?

Comment: Response time did not decrease at all. :/ I have created Http api gateway

Comment: @D.Richard The use of CloudFront is relevant when you website (single page or not) talks to a backend API service over a HTTP REST or GraphQL API and more globally, with dynamic content.